# Django Elastic Beanstalk hosted application server not found

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a Django application that I'm hosting with Elastic Beanstalk. I have setup a hosted zone & configured it with a new domain name. The site is accessible from the domain I setup & works fine, but for some reason at random times I will run into "We can’t connect to the server at www.***.com" for no apparent reason. The health of my environment says 'Ok' & I can't see any reason that it shouldn't be finding the server. I'm all out of ideas as to why I'm running into this error on occasion. (Note: It's not an internet issue, I have tried on many different devices & connections and the issues still arises after a few refreshes or route changes.)